# CSS for form in freemarker

Tags: html, css

I have one `div` which contains one button and one form. Inside the form I have a button.

```
<div style="text-align : center;">
<button id="backButton" class="backButton" value="close" style="width: 100px;">Back</button>
<form method="POST" action="${rc.getContextPath()}/payasiaotclaims/generateIndividualOTClaimReport.json?id=${claimId}" target="_blank">
    <button id="reportButton" class="reportButton" value="report" style="width: 100px;">Report</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Now the buttons are coming like stack one top of each other, but I want both buttons to come side by side. What CSS should I use?

Comment: How about creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

try to give the float css attribute to your buttons

```
<button id="backButton" class="backButton" value="close" style="width: 100px; float:left;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two divs for two buttons, and give **float:left;** in css..